# Applying css to a sharepoint gridview

Tags: web-part, css, spgridview

Within my web-part, I want to make the header row of a gridview match the css from the sharepoint css class called ms-ContentAccent1-bgColor(I want to match the theme of the site).
However, when I apply the css to the Headerstyle with the Css-Class it does not apply it. Is there any way I can apply the css while using the sharepoint gridview?

```
<Sharepoint:SPGridView runat="server" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
ID="grid" 
EmptyDataText="There isn't any no Data"  
HeaderStyle-CssClass="ms-ContentAccent1-bgColor" 
AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="ControlLightLight" 
>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to override out of the box SharePoint CSS classe's.
2. In master page, take the reference of your CSS file after the out of the box CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/1033/styles/core.css"/>
```

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/Amit/styles/AmitKumarCustomStyle.css" />
```